# Question on complete discrete valuation field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $F$ be a complete discrete valuation field and $f(X) = X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} +\cdots+ a_0$ is an irreducible polynomial over $F$. How to show that

a) $ v(a_0) > 0$ implies $v(a_i) > 0$ for $i=1,...,n-1$;

b) if $v(a_0) \leq 0$, then $v(a_0) = \min(v(a_i)\mid i=0,...,n-1)$.

**Edit.** This is Exercise 2 on page 38 in Fesenko and Vostokov, *Local Fields and Their Extensions*.

Comment: You complain that it has not received enough attention. But what attention have you showed it, yourself? What do you think? You've only just stated the problem. Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- If $L\mid F$ is a splitting field of $f$, then there is a unique extension $w \mid v$ of $v$ to $L$.
- If $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ in $L$, then $w(\alpha) = w(\sigma(\alpha))$.
- write $a_i$ as a symmetric polynomial in the roots $\alpha_i$ of $f$ and use the triangle inequality to get estimates on $v(\alpha_i)=w(\alpha_i)$.